# Knowing a google+ profile id, get number of circles for a user using the g+ API

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I tried searching google and stackoverflow, but didn't found any such way!!

Is there something, some means in the google+ API using which I can get the number of circles (public information) for a particular profile, for which I have the g+ id ?

I went through that, all I found was, one can get the public information for a profile, only when that user has authenticated the app.

Although in the graph-api for FB, AFAIR we can get such public information (about posts, pages) without actually asking for permission.

I've updated my question, if you guys still think that it doesn't conform to the stackoverflow community, leave me a comment and I'll delete it, instead of giving negative votes. (friendly request)

[edit]

The idea is not to get the number of circles for a particular user, but to the get the number of circles in which is the user.

For e.g.
https://plus.google.com/u/0/117907144223534027934 - I am in 353 circles
https://plus.google.com/u/0/118337805761123404690 - he is in 15 circles

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google+ product

Comment: that's strange, I don't know why you guys see it that way! the question is related to the g+ api
Anyways, seems like a lot have similar idea about the question.

Comment: `circledByCount` returns it. Simply try it here - https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get#try-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of circles a person has is not actually public information. Google+ does not expose a user's circle structure in any way. However, if it has been shared publicly, you can retrieve the *number of people* that have circled a user. That is, the total number of people who have added that user to one of their circles. This is returned as the `circledByCount` part of the [Person resource](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#circledByCount) that comes from a [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) API call.

If you are using [Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/features/sign-in), you can also retrieve a list of people that your user has circled through the [people.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list) API call. This is not a count, but rather the list of names and IDs of the people that the user has added to one of their circles. What is important here is that the API will not surface any information about the user's circle structure, meaning that the list you get back is a flat list of users. Also, the authenticated user that you are calling on behalf of can edit the list of people your app will see when they authenticate your app.

Comment: I'm really sorry, if the question made you felt that! But the question is : how to find out IN HOW MANY CIRLCES does the user exists ? For e.g. 
https://plus.google.com/u/0/118337805761123404690 - He is in 15 circles
https://plus.google.com/u/0/117907144223534027934 - I am in 353 circles

Comment: The user you mentioned has been added to a circle by 15 users, which is the circledByCount that I mentioned in my first paragraph. This is returned in the people.get response, but only if it is marked as public by the user.

Comment: thanks! It didn't worked though but I guess that's because it's not public.